# RecyclerView в NavigationView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-navigation-view

Столкнулся со сложностями при работе с навигационным меню: как (и возможно ли вообще) вставить в это самое меню элементы RecyclerView? Не особо ясно, как преобразовать item'ы к RecyclerView в файле с типом menu. Для наглядности прикрепляю изображение с примерным внешним видом. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто не используйте NavigationView. Замените его на RecyclerView или вообще фрагмент отдельный

Comment: Если сильно хочется использовать NavigationView, то воткните в него Header со всем, что вам надо, и откажитесь от меню вообще

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кто столкнётся с подобной проблемой - нашёл ряд решений:

1. Можете создать собственный компонент - выносите его в отдельный файл разметки, там выстаиваете нужные элементы и связываете этот файл с элементом меню

```
<item
    android:id="..."
    app:actionLayout="@layout/ваш файл разметки"
    android:title="..."/>
```

Однако в моём случае этот метод не подошёл - трудно объяснить, но ваш компонент должен быть не больше по вертикали обычного item'a, иначе он будет попросту обрезаться. Не уверен, можно ли это как-то поправить, я нигде не нашёл.

2. Данный метод очень костыльный, но для моего случая подошёл. Я добавил в разметку для app:headerLayout все необходимые мне кнопки-квадраты, а файл разметки меню попросту оставил пустым. Обработку нажатий сделал через банальный android:onClick. Грубо, но для банального перемещения между активностями работает хорошо)
   Надеюсь, кому-то пригодится.